# Convert any audio files to mp3 format codeigniter ffmpeg

Tags: php, codeigniter, audio, ffmpeg

I want to convert uploaded audio files to mp3 with ffmpeg in codeigniter.I've put the ffmpeg files in my codeigniter root folder.And here is my code controller,

```
$this->upload->initialize(
    array(
        "upload_path"   => './uploads/',
        "overwrite"     => FALSE,
        "max_filename"  => 300,
        "encrypt_name"  => TRUE,
        "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
        "allowed_types" => "mp3|amr",
        "max_size"      => $this->settings->info->file_size,
    )

);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('audio_file')) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->template->jsonError(lang("error_97") . "<br /><br />" .
    $this->upload->display_errors() . "<br />" . mime_content_type($_FILES['audio_file']['tmp_name']));
}

// $data = $this->upload->data();
$data                 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$video_path          = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
$directory_path      = $data['upload_data']['file_path'];
$directory_path_full = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
$file_name           = $data['upload_data']['raw_name'];

exec("ffmpeg -i " . $directory_path_full . " " . $directory_path . $file_name . ".mp3");

$file_name = $file_name . '.' . 'mp3';

$audioid = $this->feed_model->add_audio(
    array(
        "file_name" => $file_name,
        "file_type" => $data['file_type'],
        "extension" => $data['file_ext'],
        "file_size" => $data['file_size'],
        "userid"    => $this->user->info->ID,
        "timestamp" => time()
    )
);
```

Next what is code to convert the audio file to mp3 using ffmpeg.Or any other way to do this?Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: You cannot convert audio files with PHP. either you can use linux libs via `exec` or use other web services via API.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert files using PHP but you can use **ffmpeg**

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp3
```

in PHP you can use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute above command

```
exec("ffmpeg -i /path/to/input.mp4 /path/to/output.mp3");
```

Comment: Which path should I give for input and output path

Comment: Input is uploaded file and output is as the name and path you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But it's not working with the code.Updated in question

Comment: Can I install ffmpeg using cmd lines in terminal.I've not installed just copy the ffmpeg folder to my codeigniter path

Comment: https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg

Comment: @saranya For Linux the easiest method is to [download a static build](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Then either place the `ffmpeg` executable file in your `PATH` or just provide the full path to the `ffmpeg` executable file.

Comment: I've already placed it in my C drive and I've tried like this to convert videos to flv format `$ffmpegPath ='C:\FFMPEG';
  
  list($name, $ext) = explode('.', basename($_FILES['video_file']['name']));
        $converted_name = './uploads/'.'.flv';
        
        // Call our convert using exec()
        exec($ffmpegPath . " -i " . $_FILES['video_file']['name'] . " -ar " . $this->audioSampleRate . " -ab " . $this->audioBitRate . " -f flv -s " . $this->videoWidth . "x" . $this->videoHeight . " " . $converted_name . " | " . $flvtool2Path . " -U stdin " . $converted_name);`But not working